# JSR223 Pre Processor generated value looks like garbage data after encryption

Tags: encryption, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Our website is generating a dynamic loginkey which uses AES. Now, since I'm not using the encrypt.js code that they used on the website.

I tried to replicate this part of the code from the website using groovy:

```
var type="DATABASE";
    a2 = encrypt.AESEncrypt(a2, "<%=(String)session.getAttribute("__GETLOGINKEY")%>", 256);
    document.forms[0].a3.value = a2;
    document.forms[0].a2.value = a2n;
    document.forms[0].txtResFrac.value= screen.width;
    if (getControlPrefix.prefix){
        return getControlPrefix.prefix;
    }
```

I copied the code from https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy and replace the var text with

```
var a2 = vars.get('password'); << taken from the user-defined variables
var a3 = ""; << this is the parameter from the website login page
```

I'm passing the encrypted value using this code because I need to pass it back to the website as a loginkey

```
vars.put("a3","${new String(encrypted)}");
```

The website reads the value as

```
userid=PERFUNIADM05
password=Password_1 << This is user-defined variable
a2=********** << This is the masked password from user-defined variable  
a3=h(Dl�cg[25�z3h << This is the encrypted value using the code from this https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy.
This is being pass to the application server for authentication.
But since it cannot read it, the application is throwing an error.
encryption=EBWZJQ7XNGJN53MN7I50N2XQJ71T9LK3 << This key came from the Welcome.do page generated from encrypt.js embedded in the page.
```

This is the error from the server.log

```
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.coyote.http11] JBWEB003028: Start processing with input [txtUserid=PERFUNIADM06&a2=**********
&**a3=%07%EF%BF%BDC%05%2F%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%60%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%C6%B6%EF%BF%BD3%09%EF%BF%BD**&txtpasswd=I+am+an+idiot.&cmbOrgCodes=001&submit=Sign+in&txtResFrac=1920]
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/collections]] (http-/0.0.0.0:50443-17) I am in Timer Filter 
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Get module name for path /loginAction.do
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Module name found: default
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] Processing a 'POST' for path '/loginAction'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Looking for ActionForm bean instance in scope 'session' under attribute key 'personalizeActionform'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Recycling existing DynaActionForm instance of type 'personalizeActionform'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] Storing ActionForm bean instance in scope 'session' under attribute key 'personalizeActionform'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] Populating bean properties from this request
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils] BeanUtils.populate(DynaActionForm[dynaClass=personalizeActionform,a1=,a2=,a3=,txtpasswd=,txtUserid=,cmblayout=,cmbOrgCodes=,txtMenuCode=,txtResFrac=,cmblocale=,txtMultipleOrg=,cmbtemplates=], {a2=[Ljava.lang.String;@7a6fe440, a3=[Ljava.lang.String;@5cfc5339, txtpasswd=[Ljava.lang.String;@2212b535, txtUserid=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b9b67ba, submit=[Ljava.lang.String;@2ed3cb6d, cmbOrgCodes=[Ljava.lang.String;@10083015, txtResFrac=[Ljava.lang.String;@2784843c})
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '**********' to class 'java.lang.String'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] **Convert string '�C/��`��ƶ�3 �' to class 'java.lang.String'**
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string 'I am an idiot.' to class 'java.lang.String'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string 'PERFUNIADM06' to class 'java.lang.String'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '001' to class 'java.lang.String'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '1920' to class 'java.lang.String'
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] Looking for Action instance for class indus.collproj.action.security.LoginAction
29.02.2024 23:21:21,133 ERROR [stderr] java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 15
29.02.2024 23:21:21,134 ERROR [stderr]  at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
29.02.2024 23:21:21,134 ERROR [stderr]  at indus.common.security.aas.AES_Algorithm.decodeBase64(AES_Algorithm.java:352)
29.02.2024 23:21:21,134 ERROR [stderr]  at indus.common.security.aas.AES_Algorithm.AESDecrypt(AES_Algorithm.java:250)
29.02.2024 23:21:21,134 ERROR [stderr]  at indus.collproj.action.security.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:95)
```

What should I do to get a key readable by the website in order to properly authenticate it?

encrypt.js

```
var encrypt = {
Sbox: [99,..],
Rcon: [[0, 0, 0, 0],..,
b64: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="
Cipher: function(e, a) 
{var declaration
  for (var f = 0; f < 4 * d; f++)}
g = this.AddRoundKey(g, a, 0, d);
for (var c = 1; c < h; c++){
<< each one is created with their own function >>
g = this.SubBytes(g, d);
g = this.ShiftRows(g, d); 
g = this.MixColumns(g, d); 
g = this.AddRoundKey(g, a, c, d); }
KeyExpansion: function(f) { some for loop, if loop, SubWord and RotWord are used here... }
SubWord: function(a) { some for loop and Sbox is used here..}
RotWord: function(a) { some for loop..}
AESEncrypt: function(j, a, t) {
    var k = 16;
    if (!(t == 128 || t == 192 || t == 256)) {
        return "";
    }
    j = this.encodeUTF8(j);
    a = this.encodeUTF8(a);
    << some code>>
    var y = this.Cipher(f, this.KeyExpansion(f));
    <<some code>>
    x = this.encodeBase64(x);
encodeBase64: function(n) { for loop.. }
decodeBase64: function(e) {
    e = (typeof e == "undefined") ? false : e;
    var f, b, a, m, j, h, g, o, i = [], n, l;
    l = e ? this.decodeUTF8() : this; <<some for loop>>}
encodeUTF8: function(a) {
    var b = a.replace(/[\u0080-\u07ff]/g, function(e) { << some code.. >>}
decodeUTF8: function() {
    var a = this.replace(/[\u00c0-\u00df][\u0080-\u00bf]/g, function(d) { <<some code..>>}
```

The encrypt.js is called in this function:

```
function getControlPrefix() {
    var a2 = document.forms[0].a2.value;
    var a2n = "";
    for(var i=0; i < a2.length; i++){
        a2n += "*";
    }

    var type="DATABASE";
    a2 = encrypt.AESEncrypt(a2, "<%=(String)session.getAttribute("__GETLOGINKEY")%>", 256);
    document.forms[0].a3.value = a2;
    document.forms[0].a2.value = a2n;
    document.forms[0].txtResFrac.value= screen.width;
    if (getControlPrefix.prefix){
        return getControlPrefix.prefix;
    }
```

Hope this snippet of code helps in giving more light into the errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace this guy:

```
vars.put("a3","${new String(encrypted)}");
```

with this one:

```
vars.put("a3", new String(encrypted));
```

See [Strings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings) chapter of Groovy documentation for more details

also going forward consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because we don't know what does your `encrypt.AESEncrypt` do and what does it return. If you have a "website function" source code maybe it worth sharing it as well, this way you will get the most comprehensive help

Also `AES` is kind of broad term, the implementations could be at least the [following](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html):

- AES/CBC/NoPadding (128)
- AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)
- AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)
- AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)

See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Comment: I used this in my code //Create Cipher Factory
var factory = {Cipher.getInstance('AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding')}

// Generate SecretKey
var key = generateKey('AES', 256)

def generateKey(String algorithm, Integer size) {
    var generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm)
    generator.init(size)
    generator.generateKey()
}

Comment: so, far your advises helped me in correcting my coding mistakes.. thank you for that. I've added the code snippet of encrypt.js for your reference though I cannot put all the code.. hope you can help me with this.. desperately need to complete my task to successfully login so that I can check the rest of the jmeter scripts